# Como formatar número inteiro em moeda com javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, html, html5

Exemplo 
  var numero = 3500;
  Quero que retorne 3,500

Comment: se deseja apenas formatar uma string, use o [.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solução com Regex Do JS

```
function currencyFormat (num) {
    return num.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",").replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

José, você pode utilizar o plugin jQuery MaskMoney

https://plugins.jquery.com/maskMoney/

A utilização básicamente é essa :

```
$("#id_input").maskMoney();
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, eu tentei usar o maskMoney mas não funcionou então usei o regex do JS .